# What is actually meant by Facebook Post Engagement Stats?

Tags: facebook

Recently I have posted an ad on Facebook with objective post engagement. I spent 100Rs for one day and got over 1000 impressions. Interesting thing that i have seen there is written Post Engagement is 261. But the likes, clicks, comments etc that post has got no where around 100. So my question is that How Facebook count post engagement?

Comment: Here is how other people calculate post engagement, PE = No of post likes + comment + share + link clicks / total number of people who actually see your post i.e. total reach on your post. Sorry but I did not find any official docs on that, might insight reports help you to do reverse maths :) Or wait for some expert answer :)

Comment: Another interesting angel, so it mean if my post has 500 reach and total like, comments are 50, my post engagement would be 100

Comment: 50/500=0.1 and if you multiply by with 100 then it says, the post engagement rate is 10%

Comment: Facebook's Post Engagement is a metric based on several factors: Likes, Reactions, Shares, Comments, Post Reach, Post Impressions, Views and Viewing Behaviour. If your post had video in it, Facebook considers even more metrics like the audience of video views and the engagement within the video like minutes viewed, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't consider impressions.

I'll consider impressions/clicks (click thru rate) but not impressions on their own.

Why not? Impressions aren't a reliable metric.

Could this be a bot? Could it be faked? Are these numbers reliable?

Rank checking bots that query Google to check positions are almost always designed to imitate human users...I'm sure Facebook has an equivalent ecosystem.

I like this approach to evaluating social media:

https://www.kaushik.net/avinash/best-social-media-metrics-conversation-amplification-applause-economic-value/